# Doctrine2 FosUserBundle override column name

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm, attributes, entity, fosuserbundle

Using **fosUserBundle** in **Symfony2** with **Doctrine**.
Here are the versions :

- "symfony/symfony": "2.7.7"
- "doctrine/orm": "^2.4.8"
- "doctrine/doctrine-bundle": "~1.4"
- "friendsofsymfony/user-bundle": "~2.0.0-alpha3"

Trying to override column name such as username one.

Here is what I do :
    namespace PROJECT\BUNDLE\Entity;

```
use FOS\UserBundle\Model\User as BaseUser;
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
use JMS\Serializer\Annotation\Groups;
use Gedmo\Mapping\Annotation as Gedmo;

/**
* @ORM\Table(name="PROJECT_BUNDLE_USER")
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="PROJECT\BUNDLE\Entity\UserRepository")
 * @ORM\AttributeOverrides({
 *      @ORM\AttributeOverride(name="username",
 *          column=@ORM\Column(
 *              name    = "BUNDLE_USERNAME"
 *          )
 *      ),
  [....]
 * })
 */
class User extends BaseUser
{
  [....]
```

When I want to generate the entity with `php app/console doctrine:generate:entities PROJECT`

```
   [Doctrine\ORM\Mapping\MappingException]                                             
      Invalid field override named 'username' for class 'PROJECT\BUNDLE\Entity\User'.
```

**EDIT 1** : add of namespace and use

**EDIT 2** : Same error with type and length attributes fullfiled :

```
    column=@ORM\Column(
 *              name    = "USER_USERNAME",
 *              type    = "string",
 *              length  = 255
 *          )
```

Comment: Can you post your `namespace` and `use`s statements for you User entity?

Comment: @DaviKoscianskiVidal : done

Answer (score 2):

I spent all day on similar troubles, what worked for me to change a column name loaded is this :

```
/*
 * @ORM\Entity
 * @ORM\Table(name="Utilisateurs")
 * @ORM\AttributeOverrides({
 *      @ORM\AttributeOverride(name="password",
 *         column=@ORM\Column(
 *             name="MDP",
 *             type="string",
 *             length=50,
 *             nullable=false
 *         )
 *     ),})
```

Where MDP is the name of my database_table and password the name FOSUserbundle wants. Be sure to have specified the type, for some reason everything go wrong without it.
EDIT : This was done with FOSUserBundle ~1.3 , if you can downgrade it should work.

Comment: sorry didn't see your comment earlier.

So, you can't downgrade your FOSUserBundle and can't upgrade your symfony? Stof on github (one of the contributors) usually advise people to use 1.3.X when not using Symfony 3.X, because as it seems they are compatibility troubles or something.
Btw i just saw that you used @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="PROJECT\BUNDLE\Entity\UserRepository") , try with the syntax i used (It's not me beeing arrogant, i recalled having trouble with repositoryClass, and i wonder if it's bypassable.)
Hopefully the answer isn't far...

Answer (score 0):

Aren't you missing both column type and length?

Comment: They are not mandatory, and I am having the same error with those fullfilled